# Python -- read and append to the file

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have the following Python code:

```
with open('helper.txt', 'a+') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in lines:
        print line
    f.write('new_line \n')
```

It creates and write "new_line \n" to the "helper.txt" file first time, but fails for the some reason second time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
new_line
  File "E:/work/projects/src/helper/main.py", line 50, in main
    f.write('new_line \n')
IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

btw I'm using Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Btw, your code works on linux. This behavior is probably specific to windows. The docs mention there are differences with `mode=a+`.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of `f.read().splitlines()` and simply do `for line in f:...`

Answer (score 1):

You need to seek, this works:

```
import os

with open('helper.txt', 'a+') as f:
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
    for line in f:
        print line.strip()
    f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    f.write('new_line \n')
```

Comment: Why this mode was named "a+" (append) then?

Comment: `lines = f.read().splitlines(); for line in lines` is the same as just `for line in f` btw, except the former costs massively more memory for large files.

Comment: @Adam Smith Yep, but why am I need to to use seeks in such cases manually?

Comment: for line in f: will output newlines twice, while splitline() just once. will not output the same.

Comment: @MarinovIván for `for line in f: print line.strip()`